# battery problem while gaming

Tags: games, battery

Hey guys im having this weird problem on Ubuntu 20.04
Everytime that im playing Rocket league (with heroic game luncher)
After 20 minutes battery percentage drop down to 0 even though my AC is plugged in and in power settings battery is on "discharge"
And when i replug Ac it goes back to charging
What should i do?

Comment: Sounds like based on what you have said here the battery may need to be replaced it is not charging correctly.

Comment: maybe  but i didnt have any of these problems when i was using windows

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post hardware specifications along with a rough estimate of the battery's age, whether the AC adapter is the original one or 3rd party.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title.

Answer (score 0):

If the battery is set to discharge, that means it will discharge, which means it will go dead. You must set it to AC when the AC is connected.

Comment: how can i set it to AC?

Comment: If there is a discharge 'setting', there must be some other setting to nof discharge. I've never heard of a setting cqlled 'discharge'. But assuming it's there, since you said it is, then there must be another setting ro not discharge. I was just calling it AC. It might have a differenf name, or it might not be there at all. In that case you should esit the question so it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I put automatic suspend on 'when plugged in ' and that fixed the problem